# PHP Memory Limit - change without editing php.ini?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony2 and on the server from the hosting I pay for I can see the error of exhausting memory. Is it possible to set new limit without editing php.ini (which is not accessible)?

Comment: Did you check the manual? http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Comment: These are the php.ini values which are not accessible per the OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set it in PHP script with [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function.

[memory-limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) directive is PHP_INI_ALL changeable, which means that it can be changed everywhere.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via `.htaccess` file

```
php_value memory_limit 100M ; #Change the100M/your need
```

*Note:* this method will only work, if PHP is running as an Apache module.

Also you might benefit from reading this artice: [3 Ways to Increase PHP Memory Limit](http://www.hostucan.com/webmaster-tutorials/increase-php-memory-limit)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `.htaccess` file and put:

```
php_value memory_limit 16M # Change 16M with whatever value
```

But it could be disabled by your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the memory limit within a PHP script by using `ini_set()`

```
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php