# How to solve error memory size of bytes exhausted

Tags: symfony1

I am trying to install symfony on wamp

http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/HowToInstallSymfonyOnWindowsWithWamp

when executed second step : pear install symfony/symfony

i got an error show below , how to go round

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7680 bytes) in /home/www/sf_projects/homepage/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/widget /sfWidgetFormDate.class.php on line 39[image]

Comment: I am using WAMP5 1.7.4 with php version PHP Version 5.2.5

Comment: Do i need to install new wamp

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Memory Limit - change without editing php.ini?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544771/php-memory-limit-change-without-editing-php-ini)

Comment: Hope this would slove http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/SymfonyOnWAMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increase the memory limit for your PHP Environment by setting proper value inside php.ini

Looks like you're having just 16MB assigned, try inreasing this value.. common setting is for CLI environment.

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

You'll find the php.ini somewhere in your WAMP folder, after adjusting the value you need to restart the apache server.

Comment: I have increased the memory limit, but still showing error, I am using WAMP5 1.7.4 with php version PHP Version 5.2.5

Comment: The error generated when installing : pear installsymfony/symfony

Comment: yes the same error : Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7680 bytes) .The WAMP5 1.7.4 with php version PHP Version 5.2.5 hope the configuration is fine

Comment: then your changes didn't take any effect.. are you sure you hit the correct php.ini file? when you increased the memory limit, it must not report the 16777216 bytes anymore

Comment: thanks for your response, This the firsttime i am working on symfony, I have first try to install pear for symfony http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/HowToInstallPearOnWindowsWithWamp ,  which is followed by http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/HowToInstallSymfonyOnWindowsWithWamp unfortunately  i got the error in the second step. stuck on it, after editing the memory limit i , retried the steps but same error. ..I am working on wAMP5 trying to self learn SYMFONY thanks

Comment: hi weyandch, pls check the image attached after updating the memorylimit. the same error

Comment: would oyu mind posting a screen of the php.ini file? The value reported in the error msgs seems too low..

BTW: you're trying to install 1.4.20, that's a rather old version. You might consider switching to 2.1.. checkout symfony.com for more information on the up2date project state :)